# Django: Defining global functions to access from form and view?

Tags: django

I have a function `get_non_open_deals()` that contains some business logic, that is used both in the forms and in the view.

```
class CallsForm(ModelForm):       

    def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CallsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                        
        self.fields['deal_1'].queryset = self.get_non_open_deals(self.instance, company)
```

I have it right now duplicated both in `forms` and in the `views`. I was wondering if there is a way to define it in one place for both to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having more of a code sample to work with it's hard to show, but it sounds like this should be a method on the model.  If this needs to work on multiple models, perhaps a mixin or an abstract base class would be appropriate.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    def get_non_open_deals(self, company):
        # business logic here

class CallsForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CallsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                        
        self.fields['deal_1'].queryset = self.instance.get_non_open_deals(company)
```

At the very least, you could make it a function in your `models.py` module.

Comment: Interesting...that could be a solution.

Comment: Taking it a bit further, since it returns a queryset, might make sense to create a custom manager. Nicely spotted Jeff, looks like it's getting a bit late over here.